# Closure declaring return type

Tags: swift, swift3

Are the any differences in declaring

```
func upload(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void)
```

vs

```
func upload(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> (Void))
```

what is the best way to declare `return type`

Comment: Consider that the parameter label (and the underscore) is not needed/used at all in Swift 3

Answer (score 0):

Best way in my opinion is

`func upload(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> ())`

For now there isn't a difference in all of these, `()` is exactly the `Void` type, but which makes the intention more clear (the function doesn't return anything).
`(Void)` would actually mean a tuple containing nothing, which in the end is the same semantically, but is unclear in the first place.
So if you want to choose between those two, you should go with first, but I'd go with `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as far as i know the difference is that in second example we are returning a tuple and in first we are just returning a single type.Like we can return more than one type using tuples for instance.

```
func upload(image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> (String,Int))
```

Comment: `(T) === T` in Swift (in versions 1-3 at least, can't tell for future).